# Using ASP.NET MVC, I moved my external login partial view within the login form section and now it is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Originally, the "_ExternalLoginsListPartial" partial view was in it's own div like so...

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <section id="loginForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <section id="socialLoginForm">
        @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
    </section>
</div>
```

But I want to move it into the "checkbox" div class like so...

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <section id="loginForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

However, now when you click the external login button from the partial view, validation messages pop up for textboxes not filled in within the login form. I tried removing validation but the external login button still does not work.

How can I move the partial view within the login form but exclude it from validation and have the link work?

Comment: Where is your `form` closing `}` ? Seems like it is not closed?. I believe there is a form inside `_ExternalLoginsListPartial` too... so now you have form inside another form... which is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! That was my issue - putting a form inside another form. I ended up keeping them separated.